# postman does not validate existing email golang

Tags: mongodb, validation, go, postman, registration

I am doing a project in Go language, I already created my collection in mongodb and I made functions to insert the user data and to validate email and nickname (if they have so many characters or if they already exist in the db) the problem is that when try it in postman, it is validated if any of the two have the characters, but it is not validated if they exist in the db, just insert them in the db always with the same user and the same email, I feel that the code is not bad, What do you think?

//It is the function to validate if the user exists or not, I made another one exactly the same for the email

```
func CheckUserExist(nick string) (models.Useer, bool, string) {
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 15*time.Second)
defer cancel()

db := MongoC.Database("DebMan_N01")
col := db.Collection("users")

condition := bson.M{"nick": nick}

var results models.Useer

err := col.FindOne(ctx, condition).Decode(&results)

ID := results.ID.Hex()
if err != nil {
    return results, false, ID
}
return results, true, ID }
```

//Here I call the function and indicate that if the value it returns is true, that is, if it is true that the user already exists

```
    _, founded, _ := bd.CheckUserExist(t.Nick)
if founded == true {
    http.Error(w, "Ya existe un nombre de usuario registrado", 400)
    return
}
_, foundedE, _ := bd.CheckEmailExist(t.Email)
if foundedE == true {
    http.Error(w, "Ya existe un usuario con el email", 400)
    return
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yEq8.png)

Comment: You are only checking if nick exists, you are not checking the email.

Comment: There is the other email verification, I just didn't set it to make it too long, but it's basically the same as the CheckUserExist () function

Comment: Did you check if the db really contains multiple identical records?

Comment: yes, I already reviewed the objects that are saved and have the indicated data, even if they are repeated, it stores them

Comment: I do not know if this is a problem with postman or mongodb because I have thought a lot about the flow of my project a lot and I do not find errors

Comment: Evidence suggests that these existence check functions are not being called where you expect them.

Comment: When I change false to the founded condition, it complies with the function, that is, even if nothing exists, it returns an error

Comment: If the db already has multiple records for the same nick/email, fondOne will return error because there are multiple already. Use Find instead of FindOne and see if the result set size is zero or not. Better: add a unique index.